# c# dataannotations and jquery- how do i get them to communicate (link with each other)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I get dataanotation to talk to a custom jquery script.

```
 public class ProductViewModel
        {
            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }

        }
    @using (Html.BeginForm)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>Model.Name)
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="NewVarianceSubmitButton" />
    }

    Now jquery
    $(":submit").click(function () {
     if dataannotations are all valid  above then ...BUT HOW!

        $(this).clone().insertAfter($(this)).attr("disabled", "true");
        $(this).hide();
```

Comment: I agree with Aliostad, you just need to enable client-side validation.  If you need to write a custom attribute, I wrote a blog post [here](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2011/08/dataannotations-mvc3-unobtrusive-validations/) which links to a full project example for a `ContainsAttribute`

Comment: I read your article and I am a little confused. You suggest I create a custom attribute, put it on the string name and let mvc figure it out for me?

Comment: What are you trying to do that isn't working? when you enable client validation, MVC does 'figure it out' for you.  My post just shows you exactly how that is done from the perspective of a custom attribute.  the DataAnnotations namespace provides enough attributes that you probably don't need a custom attribute.  You _do_ need to include `jquery.validate` and/or the unobtrusive file after the jquery script in your page for client validation to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [client side validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html).

You would not write code to enable or disable. **It is all done for you by using client-side calidation enabled.**